# Getting Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, function, onclick

I am taking an input value from one page and on clicking a button I want to display it on another page in HTML.
I have exported my onclick function from one ts file and imported it in another.

Here's my TypeScript code for exporting:

```
var txt: HTMLInputElement=<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("text");
var dis=document.getElementById("dis")

export function send(){
    return txt.value
}
```

here's the HTML for the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu bar.css">
    <script src="cart.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="Number" id="text">
    <button onclick="send();"></button>
    <p id="dis"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The importing page HTML is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="import.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="display"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the TypeScript for it:

```
import { send } from "./main/cart";

var p =document.getElementById("display")

p.innerHTML+=send()
```

But I am getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined**

Answer (score 0):

Most browser support commonjs modules. So you need to compile using babel if you code like that.

Here you can either use babel or write below codes.

```
module.exports = function send(){ //codes };
```

And import as....

```
let send = require("./main/cart");
```

Other code remains the same.

Comment: I am getting Cannot find name 'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` for module

Comment: The types are needed as well in typescript...however you are getting a different error....can i have a look at the code in github??